# Coroutine in Fragment causing UIs not to render when navigating

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using a coroutine inside a fragment to handle a network request. However when I navigate away to another fragment the UI from the next fragment is blank and nothing loads. I am using lifecycle scope so I thought the coroutine would be cancelled/cleaned up on destoyed but the only way the UI returns is if I comment out the coroutine.

```
 lifecycleScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO){
        if (pdfResponse != null) {
            try {
                file = getTempPdfFile(pdfResponse)
            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
    }
}

  private fun getTempPdfFile(body: ResponseBody): File? {
    return try {
        val file = File.createTempFile("myfile", ".pdf")
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
            var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
            inputStream = body.byteStream()
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            while (true) {
                val read: Int = inputStream.read(fileReader)
                if (read == -1) {
                    break
                }
                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()
            }
            outputStream.flush()
            return file
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            null
        } finally {
            inputStream?.close()
            outputStream?.close()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        null
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me diagnose the cause of this issue?

Comment: Which UI is blank? The fragment where you launch coroutine or the one where you navigated?

Comment: Where I navigate to after

Comment: You shouldn't do this in the first place. `lifecycleScope` is cancelled when a Fragment goes off-screen or the screen rotates, and then you will have to fetch the file multiple times redundantly. Use a ViewModel to fetch files and data. But your Fragment instance might be kept alive if it's still in the backstack. As for your problem, it likely has to do with what's happening in `getTempPdfFile`.

Comment: I moved the code into the viewmodel, now when I run the app normally it doesnt work but when I run it in debug mode and the app slows down it works. So it must be finishing before the file is ready and returning null??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a suspend function in the viewmodel like this:

```
 suspend fun createPdfFile()  =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (getPdfResponse() != null) {
            try {
                file = getPdfResponse()?.let { getTempPdfFile(it) }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the view I called it using :

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
   createPdfFile()
}
```

Comment: Did this solve you problem?

Comment: Yes, the above solution is working as intended